# MVC Get model data posted from dynamically created partial views to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How do I post the dynamically created partial views model data to the controller?

My Models Class wrapper:

```
namespace Diabuddies.DAL
{
    public class Exer_Main
    {
        public Exer_Workout Workout { get; set; }
        public Exer_Routine Routine { get; set; }
        public Exer_Set Set { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My controller generates the following view (pieces):

```
@model Diabuddies.DAL.Exer_Main
<body>

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset style="width:800px">
        <legend>Workout</legend>
        <div style="float:left;text-align:right">
            <table>
                <tr style="justify-content:center">
                    <td>
                        Workout Name:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Workout.Name, new { style = "width:100%" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                      Description:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Workout.Description)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Wrokout Notes:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Workout.Notes)
                    </td>

                </tr>
                   </table>
             <br />


            <div id="AddItem">Add Routine</div>
            <div id="RoutineRows">
              </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#AddItem").click(function () {
        //alert("Handler for .click() called.");
        $.get( '@Url.Action("AddRoutineHTML", "Default", new { id = "ert" })', function(data) {
            $('#RoutineRows').append(data);
});
    });
    });

</script>
```

Each time a user clicks on Add Row the following partial view is added:

```
@model Diabuddies.Models.Exer_Routine

<fieldset>
    <legend>Routine</legend>
    <table>
        <tr style="justify-content:center">
            <td>
                Routine Name:
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.Name, new { style = "width:100%" })
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Description:
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Description)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Notes:
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Notes)
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
    </fieldset>
```

Here is the problem: How do I post the dynamically created partial views to the controller?  Right now I have:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult NewWorkout([Bind(Prefix = "Workout", Include = "Name, Description")]Exer_Workout eWO, List<Exer_Routine> eR)
        {
            //Exer_Workout stuff returns fine, I am lost on how to get the partial view data here.
            Response.Write(eR.Count); //Program breaks here, nulled out.  Obv list isn't answer
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List is the right answer. It's just how the default model binding works with a list of complex objects. You will need array indexing in your input name properties like this:

```
<input type="text" name="Exer_Routine[0].Name" />
```

And for each partial that is loaded you will need to increase the index by 1. You will probably need to write custom HTML rather than use the helpers. I would suggest trying it out by hard coding a list and getting the model binding to work first. Then you can work out how to generate the dynamic HTML.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried but didn't seem to work.  I just added the above to my partial view and tried to pass in a single instance- the list was still null.  Should my model in the partial view still be the same? Or changed to a list?

Comment: When you view source does the HTML for you inputs look like the one above: <input type="text" name="Exer_Routine[0].Name" /> It's the [0] that is the important part to get list model binding to work.

Comment: This post from Phil Haack is also worth a read: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: Your answer is correct.  What I had to do to get it to hit, however, was add:[Bind(Prefix="Routine", Include="Name, Notes, Description")]List<Exer_Routine> eR - to the ActionResult, and use the same model as in my main view (my mistake their as well).  Would appreciate if you could include the 'bind' in your answer above if others stumble upon this.  THANK YOU Mark!!  Curious as to know why though the bind had to be there.